# Is seteuid a system call on Linux?

Tags: linux, setuid

All of the literature that I have read so far on `setuid` talks about `seteuid` in a way that implies it is a system call. The section 2 `man` pages never say if a function is a system call or not, so `seteuid(2)` is no help. And if it isn't a system call, meaning the functionality is not provided by the kernel, then how can "set effective UID" be achieved?

Answer (score 6):

The section 2 man pages are *all* system calls -- that's what section 2 is for.  The section 3 man pages are all library calls, as that's what section 3 is for.  See man(1) (the manual page for `man` itself) for the list of sections and what they are:

```
   1   Executable programs or shell commands
   2   System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
   3   Library calls (functions within program libraries)
   4   Special files (usually found in /dev)
   5   File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
   6   Games
   7   Miscellaneous  (including  macro  packages  and  conventions), e.g.
       man(7), groff(7)
   8   System administration commands (usually only for root)
   9   Kernel routines [Non standard]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily verify if it is a system call or if it is defined in libc by writing a little program and running strace on it. For example,

```
int main() {
  seteuid();
}
gcc -o main main.c
-bash-4.2$ strace ./main 2>&1 | grep set
setresuid(-1, 1, -1)                    = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

So in this case seteuid is implemented in libc. See [here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/seteuid.c) for implementation